# django, the form is always wrong

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a django application and I am writing two-factor authentication by email for it (a code should be sent to the mail). But the problem arises at the stage of checking the current email and password. as I understand it, the `if form.is_valid()` check does not work and constantly returns a form error.  `Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.` and `This account is inactive.` Although I am sure that I am entering the correct user data and there is `is_active : True` in the database table. **My user model** is redefined like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_("email_address"), unique=True)

    class RoleChoise(models.TextChoices):
        standard = "ST", "standart"
        admin = "AD", "admin"
        worker = "WK", "worker"
        inactive = "IA", "banned"  

    role = models.CharField(choices=RoleChoise.choices, default=RoleChoise.standard, max_length=2)
    #another my fields
```

my **custom authorization function** looks like this:

```
class LoginOrSendCodeView(FormView):
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if "OTP_code" in request.POST:
            ...  #my other form handler, it works

        else:
            form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                email = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
                password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
                user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
                if user:
                    if user.role != "IA":
                        if user.two_factor_authentication:
                            otp_model_object = OtpModel(user=user)
                            otp_model_object.save()
                            otp_model_object.send_otp_in_mail()
                            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': OTPCodeForm()})
                        else:
                            login(self.request, user)
                    else:
                        form.add_error(None, "Пользователь заблокирован")  #my error
                else:
                    form.add_error(None, "Неверное имя пользователя или пароль")
            else:
                return render(request, self.template_name, {"form":form})
```

according to the idea, when the login and password are correct, a form for the OTP code is sent to the page, but for some reason `form.is_valid` does not work
**My FormClass**

```
class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
            "class": "form_input login_input",
            "placeholder": "email",
        }))
    password = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form_input password_input",
                "placeholder": "password",
            }
        ),
        label="",
    )
```

I tried overriding the clean() method, but nothing worked.
**and my BackEnd:**

```
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):

        """
        Overrides the get_user method to allow users to log in using their email address.
        """
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            return UserModel.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
#in settings:

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'accounts.backend.EmailBackend',  # custom backend
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',  # default backend
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your authenticate method is being called like this:

```
user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
```

However, the method signature looks like this

```
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
```

So you are passing a kwarg called 'email' that isn't being assigned when you call the function (or later for that matter).  Try this instead to start with:

```
user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
```

If that helps, you might want to rewrite your function so that what is being used is more consistent and clear, eg,

```
user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
...
def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    try:
        #your custom user has an email field, 
        #so we'll assume it is being set correctly and check it
        user = UserModel.objects.get(email=email)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        return None
    else:
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    return None
```